# Nginx: proxy_pass ignores port

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, port

I have an application with Swagger on `localhost:8080/swagger/`.

I need a redirect from `localhost:80` to actual swagger url which is `localhost:8080/swagger/` so I setup a Nginx reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name=_;
    
    location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/swagger/;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

So when I enter `localhost:80` I recieve 301 code and redirect to `localhost:80/swagger/index.html`. But I need port `8080` , why nginx ignores port in proxy_pass?

Answer (score -1):

you can modify the listen directive for the server block listening on port 80 to also include the port number:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

This will make Nginx listen on port 80 and route traffic to http://localhost:8080/swagger/ while retaining the port number in the URL.

Comment: Still does not helps. When I curl localhost/ or trying access page on browser it routes me to `localhost/swagger/index.html` with 301 code and blank page ,not the localhost:8080/swagger/index.html. It retains port, but i just need to retrieve not blank page which is on 8080 port. I changed also path from '/' to '/docs/' and now recieving 404 error which is logical, because it routes me to 80/swagger/ completely ignoring the port I set in proxy_pass.